# How to compute: $(89^{3} \bmod 79)^4\bmod 26$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How to compute: $(89^{3} \bmod 79)^4\bmod 26$??

It's easy to calculate it by evaluating $89^{3}$ first and then mod $79$, but it seems stupid to do it this way. Do we have a faster way to evaluate it?

Comment: Is there a difference between $89^3\pmod{79}$ and $89^3\mod 79$?

Comment: @QuangHoang: Yes, there is, and the original edit was in error.

Answer (score 5):

I’m assuming that the version of the problem originally posted is correct, and that what is wanted is $(89^{3} \bmod 79)^4\bmod 26$, where $\bmod$ is the binary operator. First, $89\bmod79=10$, so we want $10^3\bmod79$. $100\bmod79=21$, so $10^3\bmod79=210\bmod79=52$. Now $52\bmod26=0$, so $52^4\bmod26=0^4\bmod26=0$.

Comment: Hello Brian: Can you help me with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966334/elementary-fact-about-positive-integers-and-rational-numbers ?? I don't find the current solution as helpful and I love your way of solving the problems. thanks